# How to retrieve id for each row and then assign it to a link

Tags: php, mysql

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
if($connect) {
            mysql_selectdb('phplogin');
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum ORDER BY time desc");
            $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum");
            $data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
            $id = $data2['id'];


            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo "<div class='post'>" . "<div class='leftside'>" . "<h3 class='by'>" . $data['user'] . "</h3>" . "<h5 class='date'>" . $data['time'] . "</h5>" . "</div>" . "<div class='after'>" . "</div>" . "<div class='rightside'>" . "<h2 class='title'>" . "<a href='Forum.php?$id'>" . htmlspecialchars($data['title']) . "</a>" . "</h2>" . "<p class='description'>" . htmlspecialchars($data['description']) . "</p>"  . "</div>" . "<div class='clear'>" . "</div>" . "</div>";
            }
```

This is what ive tried but it assigns the first rows id to all links and i don't know how to do it, i am new to php and mysql thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing two queries to return the same data in the first place?

Comment: You have set the $id before fetching the query into an array. Just use "<a href='Forum.php?".$data['id']."'>

Comment: Thanks everybody i dont know why i was doing 2 querys it now works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is  that you are saving the id in `$id` - a variable. This can hold only one value.

Why are you even doing this? Both your queries are selecting from `forum`, can't you use `$data['id']`?

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<div class='post'>" . "<div class='leftside'>" . "<h3 class='by'>" . $data['user'] . "</h3>" . "<h5 class='date'>" . $data['time'] . "</h5>" . "</div>" . "<div class='after'>" . "</div>" . "<div class='rightside'>" . "<h2 class='title'>" . "<a href='Forum.php?".$data['id']."'>" . htmlspecialchars($data['title']) . "</a>" . "</h2>" . "<p class='description'>" . htmlspecialchars($data['description']) . "</p>"  . "</div>" . "<div class='clear'>" . "</div>" . "</div>";
}
```

Keep in mind that `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and hence should not be used in new code. You can use PDO or MySQLi instead. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/1557526) for more information.

---

Doing this with MySQLi and [`printf()`](http://www.php.net/printf) could look like this.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum ORDER BY time desc");

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                printf ("<div class='post'><div class='leftside'>
                    <h3 class='by'>%s</h3>
                    <h5 class='date'>%s</h5></div><div class='after'></div><div class='rightside'>
                    <h2 class='title'><a href='Forum.php?%u'>%s</a></h2>
                    <p class='description'>%s</p></div><div class='clear'></div></div>",
                    $data['user'],
                    $data['time'],
                    $data['id'],
                    htmlspecialchars($data['title']),
                    htmlspecialchars($data['description']));
        }

        /* free result set */
        mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```